# Trying to get property 'deskripsi' of non-object (View:

Tags: php, laravel, object, properties

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')

 @foreach($galerys as $data)
         <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="{{url('/ubahGaleryPost')}}">

                   {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <h4>Ubah Gambar</h4>

                    <input name="id" id="id"   type="hidden" value="{{$data->id}}" >                       
                        <h5>Gambar</h5>
                        <input name="gambar" id="gambar"  type="file">
                        <h5>Deskripsi</h5>
                        <input name="deskripsi" id="deskripsi" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{$data->deskripsi}}">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ubah</button>

                    </form>

        @endforeach

@endsection
```

controller

```
 public function ubahGalery($id){     
        $data = Galery::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.updategalery',['galerys'=>$data]);
    }


    public function ubahGaleryPost(Request $request){
        $data = Galery::where('id',$request->id)->first();

        if (empty($request->file('gambar'))){
            $data->gambar = $data->gambar;
        }
        else{
            unlink('img/galery/'.$data->gambar); 
            $file = $request->file('gambar');
            $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $newName = rand(100000,1001238912).".".$ext;
            $file->move('img/galery',$newName);
            $data->gambar= $newName;
        }
        $data->deskripsi = $request->deskripsi;
        $data->update();

        return redirect('/galeryAdmin');
    }
```

Comment: Properly update your code snippets and mention the views on top of snippet

Comment: `value="{{$data['deskripsi']}}" try this type

Answer (score 0):

`$data = Galery::findOrFail($id);` this will return `Galery` object instead of a Collection of `Galery` (except if `$id` is an array).

So in your HTML you don't need a foreach and instead could just do `$data->id`, `$data->deskripsi` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop on `galerys` as you are fetching only one result so you don't need to loop on your result so instead of that just fetch data directly.

Like this,

```
$galerys->deskripsi
```

Hope this helps:)